# How to get latest commit from development branch

Tags: git, github, fuelphp

I cloned the develop branch:

```
git clone --branch 1.1/develop --recursive git://github.com/fuel/fuel.git
```

but the files cloned do not show commits to the development branch like:

```
https://github.com/fuel/core/commit/8d964dd62e017c5e45e4827f0f0c7d1df26dd395
```

How can I get the latest commits to the development branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `core` submodule isn't up to date (it was at [e11bd4d](https://github.com/fuel/core/tree/e11bd4b63fae7b5f49ecf1eeedeb755200df70bb) according to https://github.com/fuel/fuel/tree/1.1/develop/fuel). You could update the submodule by

```
cd <the-git-repo>/fuel/core
git checkout 1.1/develop
git pull origin
```